# JIT Optimization and Weak References

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection, weak

I have the following piece of code:

```
private final List<WeakReference<T>> slaves;

public void updateOrdering() {
  // removes void weak references 
  // and ensures that weak references are not voided 
  // during subsequent sort 
  List<T> unwrapped = unwrap();
  assert unwrapped.size() == this.slaves.size();
  // **** could be reimplemented without using unwrap() ****
  Collections.sort(this.slaves, CMP_IDX_SLV);
  unwrapped = null;// without this, ....
}
```

Method `unwrap()` just creates a list of `T`'s referenced by the weak references in `slaves` 
and as a side effect eliminates the weak references referencing `null` in `slaves`. 
Then comes the sort which relies on that each member of `slaves` references some `T`; 
otherwise the code yields a `NullPointerException`.

Since `unwrapped` holds a reference on each `T` in `slaves`, during sorting no GC eliminates a `T`. Finally, `unwrapped = null` eliminates the reference on unwrapped 
and so releases GC again. Seems to work quite well.

### Now my question:

If I remove `unwrapped = null;` this results in `NullPointerExceptions` when running many tests under some load. I suspect that the JIT eliminates `List<T> unwrapped = unwrap();` 
and so GC applies to the `T`'s in slaves during sorting.

Do you have another explanation? If you agree with me, is this a bug in the JIT?

I personally think that `unwrapped = null` should not be necessary, because `unwrapped` is removed from the frame as soon as `updateOrdering()` returns. Is there a specification what may be optimized and what is not?

Or did I do the thing in the wrong way? I have the idea to modify comparator that it allows weak references on `null`. What do you think about that?

Thanks for suggestions.

### Add on (1)

Now I want to add some missing pieces of information: 
First of all Java version: 
java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.3) (suse-8.28.3-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Then someone wanted to see method unwrap

```
private synchronized List<T> unwrap() {
List<T> res = new ArrayList<T>();
T cand;
WeakReference<T> slvRef;
Iterator<WeakReference<T>> iter = this.slaves.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    slvRef = iter.next();
    cand = slvRef.get();
    if (cand == null) {
    iter.remove();
    continue;
    }
    assert cand != null;
    res.add(cand);
} // while (iter.hasNext())

return res;
}
```

Note that while iterating, void references are removed. 
In fact i replaced this method by

```
private synchronized List<T> unwrap() {
List<T> res = new ArrayList<T>();
for (T cand : this) {
    assert cand != null;
    res.add(cand);
}

return res;
}
```

using my own iterator but functionally this should be the same.

Then someone wantet the stacktrace. Here is a piece of it.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at WeakSlaveCollection$IdxComparator.compare(WeakSlaveCollection.java:44)
 at WeakSlaveCollection$IdxComparator.compare(WeakSlaveCollection.java:40)
 at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:324)
 at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:189)
 at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
 at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
 at WeakSlaveCollection.updateOrdering(WeakSlaveCollection.java:183)
```

it points into the comparator, the line with the return.

```
static class IdxComparator 
    implements Comparator<WeakReference<? extends XSlaveNumber>> {
    public    int compare(WeakReference<? extends XSlaveNumber> slv1, 
              WeakReference<? extends XSlaveNumber> slv2) {
        return slv2.get().index()-slv1.get().index();
    }
} // class IdxComparator
```

and finally,

```
 private final static IdxComparator CMP_IDX_SLV = new IdxComparator();
```

is an important constant.

### Add on (2)

Observed now that indeed NPE occurs even if 'unwrapped = null' is present in updateOrdering().

Weak references may be removed by java runtime 
if no strict reference holds **after jit optimization**. 
The source code seems not important at all.

I solved the problem the following way:

```
public void updateOrdering() {
Collections.sort(this.slaves, CMP_IDX_SLV);
}
```

without any decoration inserted to prevent slaves to be garbage collected 
and the comparator in CMP_IDX_SLV enabled to handle weak references to null:

```
    public    int compare(WeakReference<? extends XSlaveNumber> slv1, 
              WeakReference<? extends XSlaveNumber> slv2) {
    XSlaveNumber sSlv1 = slv1.get();
    XSlaveNumber sSlv2 = slv2.get();
    if (sSlv1 == null) {
    return sSlv2 == null ? 0 : -1;
    }
    if (sSlv2 == null) {
    return +1;
    }
    assert sSlv1 != null && sSlv2 != null;

    return sSlv2.index()-sSlv1.index();
    }
```

As a side effect, ordering the underlying list List> slaves; 
puts the void weak references at the end of the list, where it can be collected later.

Comment: I doubt it removes the `unwrap()` call itself, but unless `unwrapped` is never used afterwards, it's eligible to be collected. In either case, a null assignment or not, it's relying on implementation details of the garbage collector.

Comment: It's just a theory, but the compiler *might* notice that the return value of `unwrap()` isn't actually being used and optimize by not storing it (eliminating the `unwrapped` variable altogether). Whatever you try, you'll always lose in a fight against the compiler. What you *could* do is sort the unwrapped list and then re-wrap them.

Comment: Show us the stack trace and the `unwrap` method. The problem is most likely in your code, not the JIT.

Comment: Have you considered extending WeakReference class to contain information required by sort operation?

Comment: No even halfway valid JITC would eliminate a method call (except by inlining).  That would be a major no-no.  But with or without the JIT the unwrapped List is eligible to be GCed as soon as there are no longer any future references to it.  Likely this does not occur in the non-JITC case because of the way the Java stack works, but there's nothing in the language definition to prevent it.

Comment: And there's always a possibility that a weak reference will be cleared, even if the object it references still exists.  GC does this in certain situations.

Comment: ok, i updated my view: it is probably the assignment of the return value of the method invocation, not the invocation as such.

Comment: @hotlicks well, the referencee of a weak reference should not be cleared if there is a strong reference on it still. unwrapped provides such a reference, at least without optimization.. right? at least during sorting.

Comment: That's what you'd think, isn't it.

Comment: yes. and what do you think? ;-)

Comment: That’s specified in [JLS§12.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1-400): “*Optimizing transformations of a program can be designed that reduce the number of objects that are reachable to be less than those which would naively be considered reachable.*”. You could simply sort your `unwrapped` list, followed by recreating the list of `WeakReference`s. That would not only fix the problem but simplify the code, as even the `unwrap` method doesn’t need to change the incoming list, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I examine your source code, and I got NullPointerException  when JIT compile my method corresponding to your method "updateOrdering" and GC occurs during sorting.

But I got NullPointerException when Collections.sort whether with or without unwrapped = null.
This maybe occurs difference between my sample source code and yours, or Java version difference. I will examine if you tell Java version.

I use java below version.

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

If you want to cheat on JIT compilation, the below code insert your source code instead unwrapped = null(e.g.). Then, JIT compilation doesn't eliminates unwrapped code.

```
long value = unwrapped.size() * unwrapped.size();
if(value * value % 3 == 1) {
  //Because value * value % 3 always is 1 or 0, this code can't reach. 
  //Insert into this the source code that use unwrapped array, for example, show unwrapped array.
}
```

My examination result is below.

- If JIT don't optimize my method corresponding to updateOrdering, no NullPointerException occurs.

  If JIT optimize my method, then NullPointerException occurs at some point.

  If JIT optimize my method inserting the above source code cheating JIT compiler, then no NullPointerException occurs.

So, I(and you) suggest JIT optimze eliminates unwrapped code, then NullPointerException occurs.

By the way, if you want to show JIT compiler optimization, you invoke java with -XX:+PrintCompilation.
If you want to show GC, with -verbose:gc.

Just for information, my sample source code is below.

```
public class WeakSampleMain {
    private static List<WeakReference<Integer>> weakList = new LinkedList<>();
    private static long sum = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("start");
        int size = 1_000_000;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Integer value = Integer.valueOf(i);
            weakList.add(new WeakReference<Integer>(value));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            jitSort();
        }
        GcTask gcTask = new GcTask();
        Thread thread = new Thread(gcTask);
        thread.start();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            jitSort();
        }
        thread.interrupt();
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    public static void jitSort() {
        List<Integer> unwrappedList = unwrapped();
        removeNull();
        Collections.sort(weakList, 
                new Comparator<WeakReference<Integer>>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(WeakReference<Integer> o1,
                            WeakReference<Integer> o2) {
                        return Integer.compare(o1.get(), o2.get());
                    }
        }
                );
        for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(weakList.size(), 1000); i++) {
            sum += weakList.get(i).get();
        }
        unwrappedList = null;
//          long value = (sum + unwrappedList.size());
//          if((value * value) % 3 == 2) {
//              for(int i = 0; i < unwrappedList.size(); i++) {
//                  System.out.println(unwrappedList.get(i));
//              }
//          }
    }

    public static List<Integer> unwrapped() {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(WeakReference<Integer> ref : weakList) {
            Integer i = ref.get();
            if(i != null) {
                list.add(i);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void removeNull() {
        Iterator<WeakReference<Integer>> itr = weakList.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            WeakReference<Integer> ref = itr.next();
            if(ref.get() == null) {
                itr.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class GcTask implements Runnable {
        private volatile int result = 0;
        private List<Integer> stockList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                if(Thread.interrupted()) {
                    break;
                }
                int size = 1000000;
                stockList = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    stockList.add(new Integer(i));
                }
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("size : " + stockList.size());
                }
            }
        }

        public int getResult() {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your comments helped a lot. From experiments i can never be sure that unwrapped = null protects agains garbage collection. 
It may depend on certain aspects of my environment. 
Thats why i asked whether there is a specification what is optimized away and what not. 
That your experiment came out differently, may indicate that there is no specification. 

Well,... Specification just says that weak references are not GC'ed as long as there are strong references. But this is weakly formulated: unwrapped provides strong references in the java source code but if it is optimized away...

Comment: by the way, i added some useful information to my question you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 9, the correct way to prevent the JIT from discarding `unwrapped` is to use [`Reference.reachabilityFence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#reachabilityFence-java.lang.Object-):

```
public void updateOrdering() {
  List<T> unwrapped = unwrap();
  Collections.sort(this.slaves, CMP_IDX_SLV);
  Reference.reachabilityFence(unwrapped);
}
```

The presence of the `reachabilityFence` call causes `unwrapped` to be considered strongly reachable before the call, preventing collection of `unwrapped` or its elements until the `sort` completes. (The strange way in which `reachabilityFence`'s effects seem to propagate backward in time is because it behaves primarily as a JIT directive.) Without `reachabilityFence`, `unwrapped` can be collected once the JIT can prove it will never again be accessed, even though the variable is still in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your question

> If I remove unwrapped = null; this results in `NullPointerException` when running many tests under some load.

According to my understanding I do not think so that `unwrapped = null;`  makes any difference.
Yes, I have also read that making `objects = null` sometime increases the probability the object referenced will be GC'ed but I don't think it matters here because once the method ends, scope of `unwrapped` ends and is eligible for GC'ed and in your function sorting `Collections.sort(this.slaves, CMP_IDX_SLV);` is done prior to `unwrapped = null;` so it make no sense the you get NPE when adding or removing them.

I think it is just a coincidence that you get NPE, I believe if you run the test again you will get NPE with that statement also.

If you read [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)

> Weak reference objects, which do not prevent their referents from being made finalizable, finalized, and then reclaimed. Weak references are most often used to implement canonicalizing mappings.
>   Suppose that the garbage collector determines at a certain point in time that an object is weakly reachable. At that time it will atomically clear all weak references to that object and all weak references to any other weakly-reachable objects from which that object is reachable through a chain of strong and soft references. At the same time it will declare all of the formerly weakly-reachable objects to be finalizable. At the same time or at some later time it will enqueue those newly-cleared weak references that are registered with reference queues.

So it is really possible when you constructed the `List` from `unwrap()` some objects might have been marked `finalized` and while your `Collection.sort` is working some `WeakRefrence` are assigned `null`. And the point stated by [Mattias Buelens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814607/java-jit-optimization-and-weak-references#comment31210313_20814607) is perfectly valid you'll always lose in a fight against the compiler.

> If you agree with me, is this a bug in the JIT?

No surely not, I completely disagree with you.

> I have the idea to modify `comparator` that it allows weak references on `null`. What do you think about that?

I think it will solve your one problem of NPE but your requirement `removes void weak references and ensures that weak references are not voided during subsequent sort` is not satisfied.
Rather try to call `unwrap` once again, this will reduce the window for NPE to almost zero,

```
List<T> unwrapped = unwrap();
unwrapped = unwrap(); //Again to eliminate the chances for NPE as now we would have 
           //already made strong refrences to all objects which have not been `null`
```

Comment: First of all thanks for all the good answers.
First I shall give the information many of you were missing.

Comment: The easiest to provide: java version: 
java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.3) (suse-8.28.3-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: Method unwrap now changed using own iterator but should be equivalent with the following: 
<code>
    private synchronized List<T> unwrap() {
        List<T> res = new ArrayList<T>();
        T cand;
        WeakReference<T> slvRef;
        Iterator<WeakReference<T>> iter = this.slaves.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            slvRef = iter.next();
            cand = slvRef.get();
            if (cand == null) {
         iter.remove();
         continue;
            }
            res.add(cand);
        } // while (iter.hasNext())
        return res;
    }
</code>

Comment: ok, here my true comment to your first section: 
'so it make no sense the you get NPE when adding or removing them. ' 
Could you be more specific? 
Do you think NPE cannot occur? or that it occurs in both situations?

Comment: It can occur in both the situations with that statement or without that statement.....

Comment: ok, now i have observed the problem with unwrapped==null also

Comment: By the way i think without jit-optimization my code works well, right?